# Search functionality with multi search options using Asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to add multi options to a search function in my project.
I know the simple search would be like :

```
<form asp-controller="User" asp-action="search">
      <input type="text" name="search"/>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">SÖK</button>
</form>
```

and the controller will be like :

```
public class User : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Search(string search = null)
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                users = _users.GetAllUsers().Where(s => s.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));

            }
            else
            {
                users = _users.GetAllUsers();
            }
            return View("index", users);
        }
}
```

But what I'm trying to do is adding the ability to specify the search field Like: **Email address** or **By name.**
What I want to achieve is adding a DropDownList to add the ability to choose which field to look into. The Action will be something like :

```
public IActionResult Search(string search = null, string field = null)
        {
            IEnumerable<User> users;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(field))
                    {
                        if(field == "ByEmail")
                        {
                           //I'll modify this to not get all rows from the database, but wrote it 
                           //like that for simplicity 
                           users = _users.GetAllUsers().Where(s => s.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
                        }
                        else if(field =="ByName")
                        {
                           users = _users.GetAllUsers().Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
                        }

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       users = _users.GetAllUsers();
                   }
            else
            {
                users = _users.GetAllUsers();
            }
            return View("index", users);
        }
```

**But how to implement this scenario in the view ?**
How to pass multi parameters by the form in the view to the controller ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.
The view will be like :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "User"))
       {
          <input type="text" name="search"/>
          <select class="form-control" name="field">
              <option value="Name">Name</option>
              <option value="EmailAddress">Email Address</option>
          </select>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
       }
```

And the action will be the same (As I wrote it in the question).
It's all about adding a name for the input type **which should match the name in the action** and it'll be forwarded to the action.
Thanks a lot.